# Characteristic Function of a Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I can't seem to understand how Characteristic Functions are derived.

So generally, the definition of the Characteristic function is as follows,
$$G(k) = \int f(x)e^{ikx}$$
And it can generate moments as such,
$$\frac{d^m}{dk^m}\frac{1}{i^m}G(k)|_{k=0} = \langle x^m\rangle $$

But say for instance $f(x) = \frac{1}{w}$ from $-\frac{w}{2}$ to $\frac{w}{2}$ , for which we can obtain $G(k) = \frac{2}{kw}sin(\frac{kw}{2})$

We know that a necessary condition of G(k) is that $G(k)|_{k-\rangle 0}$ = 1, however, since there is a k in the denominator, I am a little confused about how we can even start to set k to 0,even though the sin term will give us a null value as well.

A similar pattern shows itself in obtaining the nth moment - for example, let us try obtaining the second moment,

$$\langle x^2\rangle = \frac{d^2}{dk^2}\frac{1}{i^2}G(k)|_{k=0} = \frac{d^2}{dk^2}\frac{1}{i^2}(\frac{2}{kw}sin(\frac{kw}{2}))|_{k=0}$$

Which we can reduce down to $\frac{4}{k^3w}sin(\frac{kw}{2}) - \frac{w}{2k}sin(\frac{kw}{2}) - \frac{2}{k^2}cos(\frac{kw}{2})$ - but from there, no matter how I simplify or try to solve, when I set k to 0, I can only obtain infinity, whereas the solution shows $\frac{w^2}{12}$ as the answer.

I think I am just having trouble with how Characteristic Functions are used to derive moments in the first place, but I would really appreciate any clarification I can get.

Comment: Your formula for $G(k)$ is not valid for $k=0$. You have to treat $k=0$ separately and deduce that $g(0)=\int f(x)dx=1$.

Comment: What do you mean separately? Should I just ignore it when its in the denominator?